# how to use javascript library in dart

Tags: javascript, dart, chart.js, dart-js-interop

I am learning [package:js](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) and the [dart file](https://github.com/google/chartjs.dart/blob/master/lib/chartjs.dart), which is a dart wrapper for chart.js.

I think this file is a bridge which connects dart and javascript. So, in this file, it must tell what javascript library this dart file is trying to connect. Am I right? But I did not find it.

What do the following statements mean? Do the following two statements tell what javascript library this dart file is trying to connect?

```
@JS('Chart')
library chart.js;
```

I have no idea how to map functions https://github.com/google/chartjs.dart/blob/master/lib/chartjs.dart to functions in https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.js. Anyone can give more tutorials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to map to a JavaScript **file**, you just need to map to JS objects and functions.

You need to add a script tag to `index.html` that loads the JavaScript file you want to map to, this will make it available globally.

You then need to map

- Dart functions to JavaScript functions, so when you call such a Dart function the call will actually be forwarded to the JavaScript function.
- Dart classes so that you can use strongly typed Dart classes which will then be converted to and from JavaScript objects when you for example pass them as parameters to mapped functions or get them as return values from such function calls.

```
@JS('Chart')
library chart.js;
```

The name `chart.js` after `library` is arbitrary. The `library` directive just needs an unique name.

`@JS('Chart')` means that the loaded chart.js library is available in JavaScript land under `window.Chart` (`window` means global in JS land and is implicit).

```
@JS()
class Chart {
```

declares a Dart class `Chart` and `@JS()` maps it to a JS class with the same name in the library scope declared above. So the Dart class `Chart` will map to the JavaScript class `window.Chart.Chart`.

```
external factory Chart(
```

The `external ...` declarations inside the Dart `Chart` class map to the JS methods with the same name.

More details can be found in the README.md https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js.

If you're still stuck you can ask more concrete questions. It's difficult to answer generic questions about how to use a package.

Comment: Thanks. I read https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js, but from the README I did not get the details you gave me. How did you learn `package:js`?

Comment: From the README ;p and from discussions where the Dart team members working on this feature provided valueable input. I also followed discussions while they were working on the feature and I used the predecessor `dart:js`. This helps getting a good picture, but I never really used any of these things in a real-world project.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate it. personally speaking, the document is so lacking and `package:js` is so difficult to use. It is too risky to use it in really world.

Comment: The docs are a bit sparse, I agree, but I didn't find it too difficult. Sure, if you're new to Dart and perhaps also don't have good JS knowledge it's a bit much at once. There were just so many huge changes in the whole Dart ecosystem the last 2 years that it will take a while until all is updated and docs improved and so forth. Currently just Dart 2 has the highest priority because Flutter depends on it and they will release 1.0 eventually but Dart 2 has to be released as well. Flutter is the killer app for Dart becoming a big player. So priorities are quite focused.

Comment: You can use web view to load javascript but currently, I didn't find any proper solution to import js file into a dart and run :
Here is a link of the file in which js is used (https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart)

Comment: Man, your answer should be added to the documentation, and should be expanded more, this answer is just the beginning of a tutorial! The `package:js` developers didn't write anything helpful like that! I got stuck at that `library` line in the README.